# Vlookup using different sheets

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have looked up other links in stack but none of them have my errors or solution.
I have 9 sheets. With last sheets being a main source file.
I have to feed a score from `sheet9` to every other sheet from 1-8
But I am getting this "#Value" this error
When I expand the column or cells, it shows "0", 
I tried every solution from other links but sometimes it shows `values`.
I have attached the links [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KsYfLK-vtdKXEBS31AJUZk3S4KnkYNv4/view?usp=sharing) of my excel file in google drive.
Can anyone help me figure out the correct way.  
`Sheet 1` is the main source file and `Group A to Group H " is where I should feed the score as per GW . 
I only need solution or need ot know what am i doing wrong, dont post the whole result, or solution. 
Thank you

Comment: If the formula returns a 0 that means the cell that has been looked up is empty. If you get an error, it would be nice to say WHICH error you're getting. They all start with `#` but what comes after that makes the difference.

Comment: I am getting #Value error.

Comment: The whole Google sheet is riddled with #Value errors. If you feed an error to a formula, that formula will also error. So you need to step back to the original error and correct that first.

Comment: @teylyn I have to calculate of GW 19, 20 and 21 See the last empty boxes. I alrdy did GW 19 manually . Then I fig it out, there must be easy way to do as I have both data to enter. So I used Vlook up on that particular cell, and its giving me error on calculation table too. If I remove the formula from that one cell  , the calculaton table will be fine and eveything will be normal .

Answer (score 1):

The first parameter of Vlookup must be a single cell or value. You are feeding it a range.

Google sheets is pushing the syntax right into your face with explanations for every parameter. All you need to do is follow the instructions.